# SSL config on Apache

Tags: tls

I have an Apache/2.4.18 server with OpenSSL/1.0.1s. I used the
[Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?server=apache-2.4.18&openssl=1.0.1p&hsts=yes&profile=old)
to generate the SSL config:

```
SSLProtocol             all -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
SSLCompression          off
SSLSessionTickets       off
```

[SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.wordsmith.org&hideResults=on) test gives these messages:

```
The server supports only older protocols, but not the current best TLS 1.2. Grade capped to C.
The server does not support Forward Secrecy with the reference browsers.
```

Also, in "handshake simulation" it gives the message:

```
Apple ATS 9 / iOS 9  R  Server sent fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

How do I get rid of these, especially the last one so that iOS 9 users can connect without any problems?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe you have `SSLProtocol` statement in `mods-enabled/mod_ssl.conf` or somewhere else that restricts it?

Comment: Is it possible there is a TLS terminator / proxy between your Apache and the Internet? But I'd look at all the included config files first.

Answer (score 1):

You should get a SHA2 certificate, first of all, as Chrome requires it.

Your ssl configuration should look like this:

```
Listen 443
SSLEngine on
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:!RC4+RSA:+HIGH:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!MD5:!DES
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/key
SSLCACertificateFile /path/to/cacert
```

Optionally you could add these for extra security:

```
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
Header always set X-ServerId 1
```

Honoring the order of the cipher suite is not mandatory.

Comment: Does not explain why they get TLS 1.0 only, when their config should get them TLS 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend testing your site with these tools: 
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/
https://ssl-tools.net/

they will give you significant insights into whether your server is set up correctly, and provide links to making things better